# How to truncate a table in Cassandra using java

Tags: java, cassandra, truncate

I have an Apache Spark job written in java in which I am able to access and write to a Cassandra table. How can I truncate the table?

Comment: Which java client are you using ? see is this helps https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cassandra/cassandra_truncate_table.htm

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code or knowing which Java driver you are using, "yes" I do have an idea on how to truncate a table.  Call the `execute` method on your `Session`, and pass the `TRUNCATE` command to it:

```
    Session session = cluster.connect();
    session.execute("TRUNCATE keyspace_name.table_name;");
```

If that can't work for you, then you might have to be a little more specific with your question.